# Secured authentification for users symfony2

Tags: symfony, authentication

I use symfony2 in my project, i have an entity employee that includes all informations of the emlpolyee and also the username and password to do the login to his session. i want to create a secured authentification to the employee but when i check the documentation of FOS Userbundle and SonataUserBundle i see that i should create a new entity USER that includes new usernames and passwords. but i want to use usernames and passwords stored in my entity employee. this is my entity:
employee.php

```
class employee
{

private $codeEmployee;

//////


private $username;


private $password;



public function getCodeEmployee()
{
    return $this->codeEmployee;
}

/////


public function setusername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}


public function getusername()
{
    return $this->username;
}


public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}


public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

////////
```

}

how to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) explains the procedure to do that.

Your Employee class must extend the base User class :

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="employees")
 */
class Employee extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $codeEmployee;

    // Optional
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    public function getCodeEmployee()
    {
        return $this->codeEmployee;
    }

    public function setCodeEmployee($codeEmployee)
    {
        $this->codeEmployee = $codeEmployee;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Don't forget to configure FOSUserBundle to choose your user class :

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Employee
```

The rest of the configuration (security.yml file, the FOSUserBundle routing files and the other commands to launch) is explained is the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).

The [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) also explain how to extend the User entity and to override the form.

Comment: But in employee entity i have a string id which is codeEmployee and i have not construct function.

Comment: So the constructor is optional. And you must declare your codeEmployee as a Column. I edit my answer.